# Apache - Mercurial - Authentication - Active Directory groups / LDAP groups

Tags: apache, authentication, mercurial, apache2, ldap

OS: Linux OpenSUSE
Version control - Mercurial
Apache2

I run http ://my.os.name/ it gives me a page - thus apache is running.
I run http ://my.os.name:/hg           - It shows me Mercurial page, thus mercurial is 
                                             showing up on http Internet Explorer page.

I'm able to create repositories/or do normal work in Mercurial.

What I need.
1. When I open the above Hg link
   then, instead of showing me the Mercurial(Hg) repository page home page, it should first check whether I belong to my company or not i.e. it should authenticate using Windows Active Directory or LDAP server.

1. If I'm making any changes to a file or create a directory / repository in Hg, then it should make sure / authenticate/verify whether I have valid access to do that operation or not.

HOW can I do this, I need step by step help as I'm new in Apache/Mercurial authentication setup.

I have almost read all the Online help in setting this up and so far I'm able to get to a point whether when I open Hg link, I get a popup for username/password prompt, but its not taking it / not working.

I also dont want to create .htpasswd/ .htaccess or digest files. What I'm wondering is that if in Windows Active Directory, if I have a Security group created for ex: Company/Project1_readers, Company/Project1_Contributors, Company/Project1_Repository1_Readers, Company/Project1_Repository2_Contributors... and in those AD security group ids, if I have all the developers added, then using these groups in AD, I want to grant access to developers instead of adding those users in .hg/hgrc file.
(This is what usually we do in TFS (Team foundation Server) to grant/revoke access) instead of messing with files (adding/removing users) in every repository etc.

How can I do the above?

Kindly advise if the best way is only creating .htpasswd/.htaccess/.htdigest etc files...if I'm wrong in achieving the above scenario.

My httpd.conf file Includes another .conf file (which contains)

=========================================

```
<Directory /srv/www/hg>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
   AuthType Basic
#   #AuthName "Apache Web Site: Login with your AD(Active Directory) credentials"
   AuthName "Mercurial Repositories"
#
#
#   AuthBasicProvider ldap
#   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
#   #AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.211.16.1:389/OU=TSH,DC=tsh,DC=Mason,DC=com?sAMAccountName
#   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.211.16.1:389/?samAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
##               #ldap://ldap.your-domain.com:389/o=stooges?uid?sub
#   AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=xyzserver,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=Infrastructure,OU=DEN,OU=KSH,DC=Psh,DC=Mason,DC=com"
#                  #"cn=StoogeAdmin,o=stooges"
#   AuthLDAPBindPassword secret1
   require valid-user
#   require ldap-user
   Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

When I'm using the abvoe LDAP URL in Jenkins, Jenkins is successfully authenticating a user while logging in, then why the same is not working when it's in this server's .conf file. Note, in apache2, the above doesn't have to be in httpd.conf file. Include concept is letting me include the file.conf and file.conf contains the above code. This is as per Apache2 directions as mentioned in httpd.conf file.

Rest of the mercurial files hgwebdir.cgi, hgweb.cgi, hgweb.config are all good (as per online blogs I have read).

I have all the required modules loaded (as they are visible in /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf file (modules which are required for LDAP auth i.e. mod_ldap, mod_authz_ldap etc etc related to ldap and apache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if prompted multiple times for user credentials in mercurial. Setup Mercurial_Keyring and then

this question comes which nobody explained in an easy way.

??? how to make the [auth] xx.prefix = servername/hg_or_something work for all repositories under servername/hg location either if I use servername, servername's IP or servername's FQDN ?

ANSWER: Arun • 2 minutes ago
        −

```
OK, I put this in ~/.hgrc (Linux/Unix -home directory's .hgrc hidden file) or Windows users %UserProfile%/mercurial.ini or %HOME%/mercurial.ini file.

[auth]
default1.schemes = http https
default1.prefix = hg_merc_server/hg
default1.username = c123456

default2.schemes = http https
default2.prefix = hg_merc_server.company.com/hg
default2.username = c123456

default3.schemes = http https
default3.prefix = 10.211.222.321/hg
default3.username = c123456

Now, I can checkout using either Server/IP/Server's FQDN.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, Prompt part which was not taking my Windows Ldap credentials is now working.

What did I put wrong.
- See line: for AuthLDAPURL and AuthLDAPBindPassword, those were the culprits in my post shown above.
- Cause was, I was new to Windows AD/LDAP concept, so couldn't get a hold of anyone from Systems team in my company. So tried my own hands. The first line for AuthLDAPURL, I got from the GLOBAL configuration file (config.xml) of one of our Jenkins instance.

Jenkins GUI for showing config doesn't show passwords (as they are masked) so there you'll see Manager's DN password as "* * * * * *". 
So, I thought I should open the config.xml file of Jenkins instance and got the password "secret1" from there. Actually "secret1" is just an example, in reality it was some crazy value over there like "VVX12##!5GH".

So basically I used that earlier which didn't work as for LDAP authentication to work correctly, you have to talk to someone in SYSTEMS team or the person WHO actually did the setup in Jenkins instance for LDAP authentication there.

Finally I got the password, and it worked.

## Resolution: See below what I changed.

- One important thing to notice is that, in Jenkins, AUTHURL for LDAP was:

  AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.211.16.1:389/OU=TSH,DC=tsh,DC=Mason,DC=com?sAMAccountName

but,
from a Unix/Linux/in my case, SUSE machine, we have to change this line a little bit to

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.211.16.1:389/OU=TSH,DC=tsh,DC=Mason,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub
```

For more on this (Apache2.2 on connecting to Windows AD(Active Directory) authentication):
PS: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html

and then 
- I put the correct password for cn=xyzserver (Manager DN user id) in the file and all was good then.

Snapshot of apache config file or the file which you have created separately and included in your httpd.file or through /etc/sysconfig/apache2 filer (variable APACHE_INCLUDE...) now looks like:

```
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/hg>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "LDAP Access - Mercurial"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.211.16.1:389/OU=TSH,DC=tsh,DC=Mason,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub

#AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.211.16.1:389/OU=TSH,DC=Mason,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

   AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=xyzserver,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=Infrastructure,OU=DEN,OU=KSH,DC=Psh,DC=Mason,DC=com"

   AuthLDAPBindPassword CorrectPassword!

#   require ldap-user c149807
#   AuthUserFile "/dev/null"

   require valid-user
   Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

I'll work on getting the user access part now on the actual repository as Auth part is done from IE(Internet Explorer) to Hg(Mercurial) from Linux/Unix/OpenSUSE machine.